# Multiple @Font-Face

Tags: css

I want to load multiple @font-face in project @font-face in a main css file. I downloaded the files woff, but they are not loaded in web page. How to use font-face for local files?

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Ubuntu';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url('../Fonts/font1.woff');
  src: local('☺'), 
  url('font1.woff') format('woff');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Ubuntu';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: "../Fonts/font2.woff";
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by “for local files”? Do you want to use the fonts locally in your computer only? And why do you ask about multiple `@font-face`? Does a simple `@font-face` work for you?

Answer (score 1):

This solution is crossbrowser and works with local fonts:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Exo";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: url("/font/exo/Exo-Regular-webfont.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
         url("/font/exo/Exo-Regular-webfont.woff") format("woff"),
         url("/font/exo/Exo-Regular-webfont.ttf") format("truetype"),
         url("/font/exo/Exo-Regular-webfont.eot"), local("Exo-Regular"), 
         url("/font/exo/Exo-Regular-webfont.svg#ExoRegular") format("svg");
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Exo";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
    src: url("/font/exo/Exo-DemiBold-webfont.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
    url("/font/exo/Exo-DemiBold-webfont.woff") format("woff"),
    url("/font/exo/Exo-DemiBold-webfont.ttf") format("truetype"),
    url("/font/exo/Exo-DemiBold-webfont.eot"), local("Exo-Bold"),
    url("/font/exo/Exo-DemiBold-webfont.svg#ExoDemiBold") format("svg");
}
```

You can add other fonts, but keep an eye on page loading time.

Comment: If you use the `font-family: "Exo";` for a heading how will the browser know which one to use: the one with the `font-weight:400;` or the one with `font-weight: 700;` ?

Comment: Check the "local" attribute: one is Exo-Regular, the other one is Exo-Bold.

Comment: I'll try to rephrase my question: for example you put `font-family: "Exo";` to a `h1`. What `font-weight` will the `h1` text have? `400` or `700`?

Comment: The browser decides the best font to use. With these settings, if you specify font-weight: bold , Exo-Bold will be used. If you specify font-weight: normal, Exo-Regular will be used. If the browser cannot find a suitable font, it will generate the style starting from the nearest font available: for example, if you want an italic bold, it will take Exo-Bold then create the italic style.
If you want a perfectly good looking Exo-Bold italic, you should add it via @font-face mechanism. Hope this is clear!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25218/discussion-between-ghigo-and-barnee)